# Matching date ranges using Regex

Tags: java, regex

I need a regex to match some file names, actually they are dated logs, and I only need to fetch logs from say 24th to 31st. Also there are 2 type of logs.

Log filenames are as follows:

```
log_file_first-Type_24-03-2013
log_file_second-Type_24-03-2013
```

I have tried following:

```
log_file_(first|second)\-Type_(2,3)(4,1)\-03\-2013
```

But this takes in 21st also, how to do this?

Comment: Extract the date and then compare in Java?

Comment: actually I am using Amazon's s3distcp and there I need to provide a srcPattern so that not all files from the source are copied but only those that matches the pattern.

Answer (score 3):

Regular expressions are powerful, but also have several limitations. There are not so good in integers' ranges. This is not an elegant solution, but works:

```
log_file_(first|second)\-Type_(2[4-9]|30|31)\-03\-2013
```

Comment: It says I cannot accept your answer, I will accept when I can.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
log_file_(first|second)\-Type_(2[4-9]|3[01])\-03\-2013
```

Answer (score 0):

```
log_file_(first|second)-Type_(2[4-9]|3[01])-03-2013
```